# how to deal with RAM size on R

Tags: r, memory, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I need to run an R script witch needs to handle lists of 2.9 GB and 1.7 GB etc. on a Raspberry Pi2, that means on a device with 1GB RAM.

As a consequence, my script (run in the Raspbian terminal) stops running when R’s memory requirement exceeds the available memory.

Does anyone now a trick (for instance with a virtual RAM) to bypass this kind of limit?

Comment: Please provide details what you want to do with said lists.

Comment: Re-write your script so you don't have 100% of the list in RAM memory at one given time is the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily [increase the amount](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1605) of swap on your raspian.

That will solve your problem in an easy way however it will be slow and it will kill your sdcard sooner or later.

What you should rather do is rewrite your script so it doesn't use so much memory and look into packages `ff` and `bigmemory` which are built to address memory issues (which are not Pi specific).